# .net All threads hang on and are blocked

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, garbage-collection

My question is : Why could in general all threads be blocked and hang on in .Net wpf application?

We produce a WPF .Net application. Some users report occasional freezes of the main thread. The usual scenario is :

1. Application works for about 1-3 hours without any problem.
2. Application becomes occasionally unresponsive for about 5-15 seconds 3-10 times per hour.
3. Applcation restart doesn't help.

We strongly suspect that this is not just UI thread is blocked but also all other threads are blocked too.

We added a timer that writes `DateTime.Now` every 4 seconds to the text file and get the following output in the file :

```
11/21/2015 10:55:10
11/21/2015 10:55:14
11/21/2015 10:55:18
11/21/2015 10:55:22
11/21/2015 10:55:29
11/21/2015 10:55:37
11/21/2015 10:55:41
11/21/2015 10:55:45
11/21/2015 10:55:49
```

So, the timer thread was blocked between 29th and 37th second.

First, we suspected Garbage Collector perfoms full blocking collection. However, we added a GC collection notifier and have not get any notifications from GC.

Here is how our GC collection logging looks like :

```
public class GCNotifier: IDisposable
    {
        private readonly int _notificationLoopIntervalMs;
        public bool IsEnabled = true;

        public GCNotifier(int notificationLoopIntervalMs = 50)
        {
            _notificationLoopIntervalMs = notificationLoopIntervalMs;
            GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(10,10);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(NotificationLoop);
        }

        void NotificationLoop()
        {
            while(IsEnabled)
            {
                var status = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach();
                if (status == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                    //Log GC.Collect is approaching here
                else
                    continue;

                status = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
                if (status == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                    //Log GC collection completed
                Thread.Sleep(_notificationLoopIntervalMs);
            }

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            IsEnabled = false;
            GC.CancelFullGCNotification();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the application process an operation on main UI thread intermittently which is supposed to be run on a background thread?

Comment: It is possible to have this kind of issues due to network delays, database issues etc.

Comment: If an application restart doesn't help, it could be that there is a process that stays hanging around holding a resource, like a file, so the new application process hangs when it tries to get access to it. Can you see this process in the task manager and kill it?

Comment: @KosalaW Yes, we have lots of database and network requests. Could you please explain in more details how it can cause freezing of all threads?

Comment: @AndrewPlakhotnyi If you try to retrieve or execute a long running database process without using Async methods, it will freeze your UI thread completely. I think that's what is happening in your system. There are quite a few things that you can do. Use a proper log-in mechanism and identify all your slow C# methods, stored procs , web service calls etc. Use C# stop watch to get start and end times. Then try to improve them. Once that's done, try to convert them in to Async, background threads etc. Converting everything in to async may introduce workflow issues. Just be mindful of them.

Comment: @KosalaW All threads freeze. Not only UI thread.

Comment: That's possible depending on the severity of the issue. I don't think anyone can conclusively tell which threads are blocked and which threads are not blocked without referring to a log. That's why it's important to find out where the exact issue is. So you need to have some kind of log which you can use to figure out the exact situation.